# Endless loop in .bashrc prevents from getting to shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a very unusual problem... I messed with my `.bashrc` file and I have managed to put there a kind of a loop. Well, it's not a loop strictly speaking, but it gets stuck because of some missing library, and therefore I cannot get to the shell. And since I cannot get to the shell, I have absolutely no idea how to solve this. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If don't have an [install disc](https://www.archlinux.org/download/), you should create one.  The link I put is for Arch but you can use any distributions of your choosing.

Once you do, run the livecd and from there it is a matter of mounting your filesystem:

```
mount /dev/sda1 # usually something similar
```

From here just navigate to the `.bashrc` correct the line that needs changing.  `umount` and reboot to your original system.

Comment: Well, this is not an ordinary PC but a raspberry Pi, but you inspired the final solution. I just created a new raspbian sd card and put the "damaged" installation in an USB card reader. Then I just fixed .bashrc and switched the cards again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find a new install disk to modify the file. Get to the raw shell using ctrl alt f1 and sign in as root, or another user. From there, you can access your .bashrc and restore access to the shell.
This requires that you set up root or an alternative user before hand. If you have graphical user management available ala Ubuntu Manage Users, you can set up the account immediately. Failing that, use tijko's answer. If all else fails, >install gentoo.

Comment: No, I think I cannot do that. First of all, the problem is with root's bashrc, second of all, there's just one user, and that's root, third: I have tried, Ctrl+Alt+F1 does nothing.

Comment: @user3095695 usually there are 6 virtual terminals by default.  You might need to try Ctrl-Alt-F2 ... F6 where each function represents a different terminal

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ssh -t user@host /bin/sh`, then edit the .bashrc file as needed.

The `-t` option opens a pseudo-tty, which is normally for running screen-based programs, and exits once the executed program completes. In this case you're using it to run the regular Bourne shell, `/bin/sh`, instead of bash (the Bourne again shell). It will act like a normal shell for the most part.

Comment: Can I do this with putty, or do I need another Linux machine? Just curious, because the only Linux machine I have right now is the one "broken". Thanks.

Comment: @user3095695: You should be able to do this from any ssh client, putty included. This does require that an ssh daemon is running on the "broken" machine, of course, and access must be set up for a user who can edit the broken .bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to single user mode and fix it from there. Some distributions call it recovery mode, but in almost all cases you can access that from the bootloader menu.